# Would anaerobic glycolysis create more ATP than aerobic respiration

Tags: human-biology, energy, anaerobic-respiration

I know the fact that [anaerobic glycolysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaerobic_glycolysis) is first step of [aerobic respiration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_respiration).

If fast twitch muscles use anaerobic glycolysis to get 2 atp at rate that 100 times faster than oxidative phosphorylation according to [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaerobic_glycolysis) Wikipedia site:

> It replenishes very quickly over this period and produces 2 ATP molecules per glucose molecule,[3](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaerobic_glycolysis) or about 5% of glucose's energy potential (38 ATP molecules).[4][5] The speed at which ATP is produced is about 100 times that of oxidative phosphorylation.

This means that it may be even more than 100 times due to other steps in aerobic respiration.

My question is would anaerobic glycolysis create more ATP than aerobic respiration in the same time interval , because if we consider that aerobic respiration creates 38 ATP molecules in x time then according to the previous Wikipedia site, I mentioned before anaerobic glycolysis, would be able to create 200 ATP molecules in x time which is much more than aerobic respiration.

What I don't get is that, it is said that aerobic respiration creates more ATP than anaerobic glycolysis?